# How to properly delete an object from table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made a delete function in my controller but it doesn't work the proper way. It always deletes the last object in the array-table. What can be the problem?

Thanks!

app.js

```
table.controller('TodoCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $localStorage) {
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
        "extraTodo": [],
        "todos":[
            { "id":1,"text":"learn AngularJS", "color":"red", "progress":30},
            { "id":2,"text":"build an AngularJS app", "color":"blue", "progress":30},
            { "id":3,"text":"learning Python", "color":"red","progress":70},
            { "id":4,"text":"build an Python app", "color":"blue", "progress":80},

        ]

    });

    $scope.extraTodoData = $localStorage.extraTodo;
    $scope.todoData = $localStorage.todos;  

    $scope.Delete = function (del) { 
        console.log(del);
        var result = confirm('Are you sure?');
        if (result === true) {  
            var index = getSelectedIndex(del);
            del.splice(index, 1);
        };
    };

    function getSelectedIndex (del) {
        console.log(del);
        for(var i = 0; i < del.length; i++)
            if(del[i].id == del)
                return i;
            return -1;  
    };
```

index.html

```
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ng-scope"  ng-click="Delete($storage.extraTodo)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ng-scope"  ng-click="Delete($storage.todos)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
```

Comment: Do you want to delete an object specified by `del`? Is `del` an id or an index?

Comment: You are missing brackets in for loop of getSelectedIndex function

Comment: `if(del[i].id == del)` This is particularly confusing...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to delete an object from `todos` based on its ID, you can make a function that takes an ID as a parameter, and then removes any object with that ID. Using your naming and assuming `todos` is whatever you're working with:

```
$scope.Delete = function(id) {
    todos = todos.filter(function(item) {
        return item.id !== id;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will delete the object(eg: del) from $scope.$storage.

```
 $scope.Delete = function (del) { 
        var result = confirm('Are you sure?');
        if (result === true) {  
            var index = $scope.$storage.indexOf(del);
            $scope.$storage.splice(index, 1);
        };
    };
```